# Why I cannot show $f(A\cap B) \supseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

$f:X\rightarrow Y$
$A,B\subseteq X$

The question got me to show a counterexample where
$$f(A\cap B) \neq f(A)\cap f(B)$$
and also to show
$$f(A\cap B) \subseteq f(A)\cap f(B).$$
This was done in the following way:
let $y\in f(A\cap B)$. Then there exists $x\in A\cap B$ such that $y=f(x)$.
So, $x\in A, y\in f(A)$ and $x\in B, y\in f(B)$
So this means $y \in f(A) \cap f(B)$.  $\qquad (\star)$
So $f(A\cap B) \subseteq f(A) \cap f(B)$.

However, why can I not go in the reverse direction by starting at $(\star)$ to show that if $y\in f(A)\cap f(B)$, then $y \in f(A\cap B)$?
I suspect it might have something to do with taking the pre-image, but it seems that we used the pre-image definition anyway in the first line of the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two $x$'s in the preceding line are not necessarily the same if you go backwards. In other words,

$y\in f(A)\cap f(B)$ implies $x_1\in A$ and $x_2\in B$ such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = y$, but there is no reason that $x_1=x_2$.

Comment: So the sufficient condition is $f$ is injective?

Comment: Yes that seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $y \in f(A)$, then there is some $x$ such that $x\in A$ and $y = f(x)$. Similarly, if $y \in f(B)$, then there is some $z$ such that $z \in B$ and $y = f(z)$.

Even knowing both of these are true, it is possible that $x \neq z$, so that no element in both $A$ and $B$ will be such that it's image is $Y$, although there may be elements in either set whose image is $Y$.

A good example of this is to take the case where $A , B$ are disjoint but $f(A)$  and $f(B)$ are not. Let $f : \mathbb R \to \{0\}$ be the function that maps every real number to $0$. It is easy to see that even if $A \cap B = \emptyset$, and neither is empty, $f(A) \cap f(B) = \{0\}$ is always non-empty and therefore not equal to $f(A \cap B)$.